# Auto confirm shipment when create shipment from Sales Order by Automation Step

Tags: acumatica

As title, i want to auto confirm shipment when I Create shipment from Sales Order screen by automation step.

Thanks all.

Comment: What do you consider as Auto confirm? At which form ?

Comment: In Sales Order screen (SO301000), i click on Create Shipment action, shipment will be created with status "Open". I want this shipment will be change to status "Confirmed" automatically as click action: Confirm Shipment in Shipment screen (SO302000)

Comment: Please clarify did I grasp your request correctly. It looks like you want to imitate clicking at buttons "Create Shipment" and then open created shipment in screen SO302000 and click confirm?

Comment: yes exactly, for more information, I have used customization code to do that but it makes many unexpected error so I want to use automation step to make sure everything work well base on Acumatica standard

Comment: can you provide your customization code which you used?

Comment: I use like Hybridzz. I override CreateShipment method. When I create shipment in SO screen, everything is work well, but when I create shipment from process screen (SO501000), only first SO is done the others is changed to Back Order (although stock item is full fill).

When i debug, this is exception I received: "Order SO - ... does not contain any items planned for shipment ..."

Comment: I saw this error "Order SO - ... does not contain any items planned for shipment .." while creating the shipment not in the confirmation.

Comment: Yes, only first Order can create shipment then confirmation, the others is not create shipment and Order is changed to Back Order

Answer (score 2):

```
    SOShipmentEntry docgraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOShipmentEntry>();
    docgraph.Document.Current = docgraph.Document.Search<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>(ShipmentNbr);
    foreach (var action in (docgraph.action.GetState(null) as PXButtonState).Menus)
                                        {
                                            if (action.Command == "Confirm Shipment")
                                            {
                                                PXAdapter adapter2 = new PXAdapter(new DummyView(docgraph, docgraph.Document.View.BqlSelect, new List<object> { docgraph.Document.Current }));
                                                adapter2.Menu = action.Command;
                                                docgraph.action.PressButton(adapter2);

                                                TimeSpan timespan;
                                                Exception ex;
                                                while (PXLongOperation.GetStatus(docgraph.UID, out timespan, out ex) == PXLongRunStatus.InProcess)
                                                { }
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }



internal class DummyView : PXView
        {
            List<object> _Records;
            internal DummyView(PXGraph graph, BqlCommand command, List<object> records)
                : base(graph, true, command)
            {
                _Records = records;
            }
            public override List<object> Select(object[] currents, object[] parameters, object[] searches, string[] sortcolumns, bool[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, ref int startRow, int maximumRows, ref int totalRows)
            {
                return _Records;
            }
        }
```

We had issues with 'confirm shipment' , the above code helped to do that. It loads the shipment document from the shipment number and finds the menu of the graph for 'confirm shipment' and clicks it.

Answer (score 0):

Best option to schedule process Confirm Shipment instead of using Automation Steps functionality.