# Acumatica - Calling Process Shipments actions from code

Tags: acumatica

I am developing an extension to Acumatica and one of the things I would like to do is execute Confirm Shipment and Prepare Invoice actions on the Process Shipments screen from code.  I also will need to release the invoice.

To simplify the discussion, at a certain point in the code I will have a shipment in the cache and a pointer to the SOShipmentEntry graph:

```
SOShipment soShipment = soShipmentGraph.Document.Search<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>(shipmentNbr);
```

At different points I would like to be able to confirm the shipment, prepare the invoice, and release the invoice.  I have done a lot of digging and I have found the ConfirmShipment method, but I get errors trying to call it - shipment counters corrupted.  I called it with:

```
SOOrder soOrder = PXSelect<SOOrder, Where<SOOrder.orderNbr,
    Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>.Select(this, orderNbr);

soOrderGraph.Document.Current = soOrder;
soShipmentGraph.ConfirmShipment(soOrderGraph, soShipment);
```

Studio compiled it, but I get the corrupted counters exception when it runs.  There is some code in the PXAction logic in SOShipmentEntry that I must need.  I just don't know how to call the action directly from code.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling the function directly like you are doing is the most obvious choice however we must understand how the the actions work in the graph `SOShipmentEntry`. By looking at the source code we can understand that the `PXAction` called is the following:

```
public PXAction<SOShipment> action;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Actions", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
[PXButton]
protected virtual IEnumerable Action(PXAdapter adapter,
    [PXInt]
    [PXIntList(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }, new string[] { "Confirm Shipment", "Create Invoice", "Post Invoice to IN", "Apply Assignment Rules", "Correct Shipment", "Create Drop-Ship Invoice", "Print Labels", "Get Return Labels", "Cancel Return" })]
    int? actionID,
    [PXString()]
    string ActionName
)
```

By digging further in the function we can notice that what is executed when `actionID=1` is much more than simply calling `public virtual void ConfirmShipment(SOOrderEntry docgraph, SOShipment shiporder)`:

```
case 1:
{
    List<object> _persisted = new List<object>();
    foreach (SOOrder item in Caches[typeof(SOOrder)].Updated)
    {
        _persisted.Add(item);
    }

    Save.Press();
    PXAutomation.CompleteAction(this);

    PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate()
    {
        SOShipmentEntry docgraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOShipmentEntry>();
        SOOrderEntry orderentry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();

        orderentry.Caches[typeof(SiteStatus)] = docgraph.Caches[typeof(SiteStatus)];
        orderentry.Caches[typeof(LocationStatus)] = docgraph.Caches[typeof(LocationStatus)];
        orderentry.Caches[typeof(LotSerialStatus)] = docgraph.Caches[typeof(LotSerialStatus)];
        orderentry.Caches[typeof(ItemLotSerial)] = docgraph.Caches[typeof(ItemLotSerial)];

        PXCache cache = orderentry.Caches[typeof(SOShipLineSplit)];
        cache = orderentry.Caches[typeof(INTranSplit)];

        orderentry.Views.Caches.Remove(typeof(SiteStatus));
        orderentry.Views.Caches.Remove(typeof(LocationStatus));
        orderentry.Views.Caches.Remove(typeof(LotSerialStatus));
        orderentry.Views.Caches.Remove(typeof(ItemLotSerial));

        PXAutomation.StorePersisted(docgraph, typeof(SOOrder), _persisted);
        foreach (SOOrder item in _persisted)
        {
            PXTimeStampScope.PutPersisted(orderentry.Document.Cache, item, item.tstamp);
        }

        foreach (SOShipment shipment in list)
        {
            try
            {
                if (adapter.MassProcess) PXProcessing<SOShipment>.SetCurrentItem(shipment);
                if (shipment.Operation != SOOperation.Receipt)
                    docgraph.ShipPackages(shipment);
                docgraph.ConfirmShipment(orderentry, shipment);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (!adapter.MassProcess)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                PXProcessing<SOShipment>.SetError(ex);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

We can understand that the best way to call it will be to simulate clicking on the button Confirm Shipment that was generated by the framework and will basically call the `PXAction<SOOrder> action` with the argument `actionID=1`. To do so we will need to do a bit of gymnastic. Here's an example where we add a button `Confirm Shipment` to the Shipments grid in the page `Sales Order`:

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {

        public PXAction<SOOrder> confirmShipment;

        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Confirm Shipment")]
        [PXButton]
        protected virtual IEnumerable ConfirmShipment(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            var soOrderShip = Base.shipmentlist.Current;
            if ( soOrderShip != null)
            {
                var graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOShipmentEntry>();

                //We are recreating an adapter like the framework would do.
                var a = new PXAdapter(graph.Document)
                            {
                                Searches = new object[] { soOrderShip.ShipmentNbr }
                            };

                //Note: Confirm Shipment is Action 1 : 
                a.Arguments.Add("actionID", 1);
                PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, () => { foreach (SOShipment soShipment in graph.action.Press(a)); });

            }
            return adapter.Get();
        }

        protected virtual void SOOrderShipment_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected del)
        {
            var shipment = (SOOrderShipment)e.Row;
            if (shipment != null)
                confirmShipment.SetEnabled(!shipment.Confirmed.GetValueOrDefault());
            del(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to test the whole project here's the customization project XML

```
<Customization level="0" description="">
    <Page path="~/pages/so/so301000.aspx" pageSource="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">
        <PXDataSource ID="ds" ParentId="phDS_ds" TypeFullName="PX.Web.UI.PXDataSource">
            <Children Key="CallbackCommands">
                <AddItem>
                    <PXDSCallbackCommand TypeFullName="PX.Web.UI.PXDSCallbackCommand">
                        <Prop Key="Name" Value="ConfirmShipment" />
                        <Prop Key="Visible" Value="false" />
                        <Prop Key="DependOnGrid" Value="grid5" />
                        <Prop Key="CommitChanges" Value="true" />
                    </PXDSCallbackCommand>
                </AddItem>
                <PXDSCallbackCommand Name="CalculateFreight" OriginalIndex="19" />
            </Children>
        </PXDataSource>
        <PXGrid ID="grid5" ParentId="phG_tab_Items#7_grid5" TypeFullName="PX.Web.UI.PXGrid">
            <Children Key="ActionBar.CustomItems">
                <AddItem>
                    <PXToolBarButton TypeFullName="PX.Web.UI.PXToolBarButton">
                        <Prop Key="Text" Value="Confirm Shipment" />
                        <Prop Key="Tooltip" Value="Confirm Shipment" />
                        <Prop Key="CommandSourceID" Value="ds" />
                        <Prop Key="CommandName" Value="ConfirmShipment" />
                    </PXToolBarButton>
                </AddItem>
            </Children>
        </PXGrid>
        <PXGridColumn DataField="ShipmentNbr" ParentId="phG_tab_Items#7_grid5_Levels#0_Columns#0" TypeFullName="PX.Web.UI.PXGridColumn">
            <Prop Key="CommitChanges" />
            <Prop Key="LinkCommand" />
        </PXGridColumn>
    </Page>
    <Graph ClassName="SOOrderEntry" Source="#CDATA" IsNew="True" FileType="ExistingGraph">
        <CDATA name="Source"><![CDATA[using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Avalara.AvaTax.Adapter;
using Avalara.AvaTax.Adapter.TaxService;
using PX.CCProcessingBase;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.AP;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.CA;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.DR;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.PM;
using PX.Objects.PO;
using PX.Objects.TX;
using AvaMessage = Avalara.AvaTax.Adapter.Message;
using POLine = PX.Objects.PO.POLine;
using POOrder = PX.Objects.PO.POOrder;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CRLocation = PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.SO;

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {

        public PXAction<SOOrder> confirmShipment;

        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Confirm Shipment")]
        [PXButton]
        protected virtual IEnumerable ConfirmShipment(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            var soOrderShip = Base.shipmentlist.Current;
            if ( soOrderShip != null)
            {
                var graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOShipmentEntry>();

                //We are recreating an adapter like the framework would do.
                var a = new PXAdapter(graph.Document)
                            {
                                Searches = new object[] { soOrderShip.ShipmentNbr }
                            };

                //Note: Confirm Shipment is Action 1 : 
                a.Arguments.Add("actionID", 1);
                PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, () => { foreach (SOShipment soShipment in graph.action.Press(a)); });

            }
            return adapter.Get();
        }

        protected virtual void SOOrderShipment_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected del)
        {
            var shipment = (SOOrderShipment)e.Row;
            if (shipment != null)
                confirmShipment.SetEnabled(!shipment.Confirmed.GetValueOrDefault());
            del(sender, e);
        }
    }
}]]></CDATA>
    </Graph>
</Customization>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also came through this shipment counter corrupted.

[Auto confirm shipment when create shipment from Sales Order by Automation Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508459/auto-confirm-shipment-when-create-shipment-from-sales-order-by-automation-step)

The answer from Hybridzz worked for me, you can check it out.