# How do I programmatically calling Update IN after a shipment is confirmed?

Tags: acumatica

I need to call the action "Upload IN" when a user sends an order to shipment. I already have the order automatically being confirmed. Here is my code which is based off of a different question's answer ([Auto confirm shipment when create shipment from Sales Order by Automation Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32508459/auto-confirm-shipment-when-create-shipment-from-sales-order-by-automation-step)):

```
public delegate void CreateShipmentDelegate(SOOrder order, int? SiteID, DateTime? ShipDate, bool? useOptimalShipDate, string operation, DocumentList<SOShipment> list);
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void CreateShipment(SOOrder order, int? SiteID, DateTime? ShipDate, bool? useOptimalShipDate, string operation, DocumentList<SOShipment> list, CreateShipmentDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        baseMethod(order, SiteID, ShipDate, useOptimalShipDate, operation, list);

        foreach (var action in (Base.action.GetState(null) as PXButtonState).Menus)
        {
            if (action.Command == "Confirm Shipment")
            {
                PXAdapter adapter2 = new PXAdapter(new DummyView(Base, Base.Document.View.BqlSelect, new List<object> { Base.Document.Current }));
                adapter2.Menu = action.Command;
                Base.action.PressButton(adapter2);

                TimeSpan timespan;
                Exception ex;
                while (PXLongOperation.GetStatus(Base.UID, out timespan, out ex) == PXLongRunStatus.InProcess)
                { }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to replicate the foreach loop but instead searching for "Upload IN" but that did not produce the desired result:

```
        foreach (var action in (Base.action.GetState(null) as PXButtonState).Menus)
        {
            if (action.Command == "Update IN")
            {

                PXAdapter adapter3 = new PXAdapter(new DummyView(Base, Base.Document.View.BqlSelect, new List<object> { Base.Document.Current }));
                adapter3.Menu = action.Command;
                Base.action.PressButton(adapter3);

                TimeSpan timespan;
                Exception ex;
                while (PXLongOperation.GetStatus(Base.UID, out timespan, out ex) == PXLongRunStatus.InProcess)
                { }
                break;
            }
         }
```

Are there any other methods to call Actions in general?

One thing I noticed with this specific action is that I cannot find its code in the source for a version 6 instance, but in version 2017, I found it as its own action but with Visibility = false. Is this action obsolete in 2017, or is there a setting to show/hide this action in configuration?

Comment: I believe the Action has been moved from automation steps (v6.x) to actual source code in v2017. During that move, the field modifier has been made protected or private which makes it disappear when you extend the graph or something along those lines. Adding that Action handler in the graph extension is the recommended workaround until you upgrade to a newer 2017 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a known bug in early 2017 versions where that action is actually not visible on screen:

[image]

This bug should be fixed in latest 2017 versions. In the meantime, the workaround is to redefine that action in a SOShipmentEntry graph extension. With that code, action will be visible and thus invocable:

```
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Update IN", Visible = false, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
[PXButton]
protected virtual IEnumerable updateIN(PXAdapter adapter, List<SOShipment> shipmentList = null)
{
    List<SOShipment> list = new List<SOShipment>();
    if (shipmentList == null)
    {
        foreach (SOShipment order in adapter.Get<SOShipment>())
        {
            list.Add(order);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        list = shipmentList;
    }

    if (!Base.UnattendedMode && sosetup.Current.UseShippedNotInvoiced != true && sosetup.Current.UseShipDateForInvoiceDate != true && list.Any(shipment =>
    {
        IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> fills = PXAutomation.GetFills(shipment);
        object fillStatus = null;
        fills?.TryGetValue(typeof(SOShipment.status).Name, out fillStatus);
        return shipment.Status != SOShipmentStatus.Completed && fillStatus?.ToString() != SOShipmentStatus.Completed;
    }))
    {
        WebDialogResult result = Base.Document.View.Ask(Base.Document.Current, PX.Objects.GL.Messages.Confirmation,
            PX.Objects.SO.Messages.ShipNotInvoicedUpdateIN, MessageButtons.YesNo, MessageIcon.Question);
        if (result != WebDialogResult.Yes)
            return list;
    }

    Base.Save.Press();

    PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate ()
    {
        INIssueEntry ie = PXGraph.CreateInstance<INIssueEntry>();
        SOShipmentEntry docgraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOShipmentEntry>();

        docgraph.Caches[typeof(SiteStatus)] = ie.Caches[typeof(SiteStatus)];
        docgraph.Caches[typeof(LocationStatus)] = ie.Caches[typeof(LocationStatus)];
        docgraph.Caches[typeof(LotSerialStatus)] = ie.Caches[typeof(LotSerialStatus)];
        docgraph.Caches[typeof(SiteLotSerial)] = ie.Caches[typeof(SiteLotSerial)];
        docgraph.Caches[typeof(ItemLotSerial)] = ie.Caches[typeof(ItemLotSerial)];

        docgraph.Views.Caches.Remove(typeof(SiteStatus));
        docgraph.Views.Caches.Remove(typeof(LocationStatus));
        docgraph.Views.Caches.Remove(typeof(LotSerialStatus));
        docgraph.Views.Caches.Remove(typeof(SiteLotSerial));
        docgraph.Views.Caches.Remove(typeof(ItemLotSerial));

        DocumentList<INRegister> created = new DocumentList<INRegister>(docgraph);

        foreach (SOShipment order in list)
        {
            try
            {
                if (adapter.MassProcess) PXProcessing<SOShipment>.SetCurrentItem(order);
                docgraph.PostShipment(ie, order, created);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (!adapter.MassProcess)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                PXProcessing<SOShipment>.SetError(ex);
            }
        }

        if (docgraph.sosetup.Current.AutoReleaseIN == true && created.Count > 0 && created[0].Hold == false)
        {
            INDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(created, false);
        }
    });

    return list;
}
```

Comment: This bug doesn't affect v6.x, it affects only a handful of 2017 versions and is marked as fixed in versions: 
17.203.0011; 17.204.0013.0001; 17.205.0005; 18.091.0009; 18.091.0024

Comment: That answers the question about not seeing the action in 2017. I did see that they have the action in place, but visible = false. What I need to know is how can I call that action or automation, whichever one it is in version 6. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Well you can't with your current 2017 version, the issue is not visibility but access modifiers. That's why the workaround is to redefine the action handler as explained in my answer. The other options would be to downgrade or upgrade.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I believe we went with updating the system to the latest now, which has that present. At that time, you were correct that it was a known issue. Marking as accepted answer.